# Pass selected li element with form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

How can I pass with form what is selected from dropdown field? So that url goes to `?s=sdf&tag=book`or `?s=sdf&tag=newspaper` in this example
http://codepen.io/filaret/pen/yazXKQ

I couldn't create my design goal with `<select><option>...` inside input element so I used Bootstrap dropdown with `.input-group-btn`.

```
<form  action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div class="input-group">

      <input type="text">

      // SELECT OPTIONS
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      // SUBMIT BUTTON
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">Submit</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: `<li>` isn't a  form element, so this would require Javascript manipulation.

Comment: Any reason not to use one of the real form elements?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work with this

```
<input id="search-hidden" type="hidden" value="">

$selectWrapper.find(".dropdown-menu li").click(function() {

    var $selectedIcon = $(this).find('.fa');
    $selectWrapper.find("#search-hidden").val( $selectedIcon.data('value') );

});
```